# Wiki等ではどのリンク記法を使うべき？

Tags: 討議, タグwiki

ご存知の通りMarkdownではリンクに名前を付けて参照することができます。

```
これは [Google](http://www.google.com/) へのインライン リンクです。
これは [Google][1] への参照リンクです。
これは可読性の高い [Yahoo!][yahoo] へのリンクです。

  [1]: http://www.google.com/
  [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
```

自分が質問・回答する際はそれぞれの好みで使えばいいのかなと思いますが、タグWikiなどの公共コンテンツの場合はある程度統一されていると作成・編集しやすいかと思います。

皆さんはどのような基準で使い分けていますか？

（編集時にリンク先がわかりやすく気軽に編集できるという点で、私はインライン記法をよく使います）

Comment: どちらでも良いと思いますが、私はつい数日前まで参照リンクの書き方を知りませんでした。参照リンクは Markdown での可読性が高いので便利だと思いますが、個人的には使わないと思います（インライン記法をプロンプトで表示させる bookmarklet を使ってますので）。

Comment: 同じくどちらでも良いと思います。私もブラウザの拡張(vimperatorのcopy.js)をよく使う関係で、Markdown用に登録しているインラインリンクを主に使っています。尚、編集エディタのハイパーリンクは参照リンクになっているようですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どちらの方法でも良いと思います。

自分の場合を紹介すると、普段テキストを扱うときはインライン記法だけを使いますが、 Stack Overflow に限っては、 `[name][1]` の記法を多く使っています。これは Stack Overflow の投稿編集エディタの影響が大きいです。

- **数字参照リンク追加**:
  投稿を編集する際に、 URL 文字列をコピーしたあと、語句を <kbd>Shift+→</kbd>で選択、<kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>後<kbd>⌘+V</kbd>(or <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>)<kbd>Enter</kbd>でリンクを付けられる。
- **数字参照リンク削除**:
  投稿を編集する際に、すでに<kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>でリンクの付けられた語句を選択後 <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> でリンク構文のみ削除できる。裸の語句が選択状態になるので、そのままもう一度 <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> で新たにリンクを付けられる。

使い分けるとしたら

- `[name][1]` 系は、 URL をフッタにまとめるためのもの
- `[name][anyword]` 系は、 段落途中に URL をまとめるもの
- `[name](link)` 系は、文章の長さとか気分にあわせて自由に使う
- `<a href="link">name</a>` は、バグにぶち当たった時に使う (使ったことありませんが)

となるかな。